# basic ansible custom module, touch file

Tags: python, ansible

I am trying to write a module that will touch a file based on user input for proof of concept purposes. For example, the following touch.yml and touch.py files should touch a file named foo.txt:

touch.yml:

```
---
- hosts: localhost   
  tasks:
    - name: testing python in ansible
      touch:
        fname: foo.txt
```

library/touch.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from ansible.module_utils.basic import *

def filename(fname):
    open(fname, 'a').close()

def main():
        module_args = dict(
            fname=dict(type='str', required=False)
        )
        module = AnsibleModule(
                     argument_spec=module_args,
                     supports_check_mode=False
                 )
        fname = module.params['fname']
        result = dict(
            changed=False
        )

        module.exit_json(changed=False)
```

It is not correct, and I was hoping someone could help iron out my logic and connect the dots.

Comment: It would help us to help you if you said what "not correct" means in your case. Is it producing an error? Is it failing to find your `touch` module? Something else? Or are you just looking for a [code-review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem. For anyone who wants to understand how to write ansible modules in python, please take note of the module.params["..."], this is the link back to the playbook yaml keys for your module.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from ansible.module_utils.basic import *
import json

def main():

        module_args = {
                "name": {"default": True, "type": "str"},
                "surname": {"default": True, "type": "str"}
                }
        module = AnsibleModule(
                     argument_spec=module_args,
                     supports_check_mode=False
                 )

        open(module.params["name"], 'a').close()

        module.exit_json(changed=False, meta=module_args)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here I am touching a file with name "name", which will be specified in the yaml playbook keys. The yaml looks like:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: testing python in ansible
      mymodulename:
        name: "testing123"
      register: result

    - debug: var=result
```

This will touch a file called "testing123".